# Snapshot recreation not working with Mini Filter

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, minifilter

I am developing a file system mini-filter driver which is being used for tracking SQL Server database files (namely mdf and ndf files). The agenda is to track all the write operations that take place in an mdf file, find the offsets and length (calling this pair an extent) of all the writes that took place, extract the blocks of data from the latest snapshot using respective offsets along with the length and finally try to recreate the latest snapshot using the older one + all the extents applied/merged on it.

Earlier I was only using  IRP_MJ_WRITE in the callbacks array to detect only the writes happening in the mdf file that I want to track but every time I apply the changed blocks data on the older snapshot to create the newer one, the snapshots don't match. The newer snapshot (say SN2) is 648 MB in size while the modified snapshot obtained after applying the extents on the older snapshot (say SN1) comes out to be 631 MB in size. Also, the extents I get every time from the mini-filter are different but somehow it results in the same 631 MB mdf file after I merge them with the older snapshot. What can be the reason for that? Would love to know this.

For a change, I added the other IRP operations also present by default in Microsoft's code but it was also of no help. The modified file is still 631 MB in size.

The problem I believe is something else and I am not being able to figure it out. Also, in microsoft's code, I found out that they are using this flag **RECORD_TYPE_FLAG_EXCEED_MEMORY_ALLOWANCE** in the mspyLog.c file. Can this be the reason for some buffer overflow happening while retrieving logs?

The base code is derived from Microsoft's official repository - https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy

I don't have any experience with filter drivers and would appreciate all kinds of help coming in. Thanks.